# Performance of polynomial functions in Mathematica vs Python

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, compile, python, benchmarking

I am trying to compare the performance of Mathematica vs Python for vectorized operations involving polynomials. The data is `floatMatrix` which has dimensions (750000, 4). The function `testFunction[x,y,w,z]` is a polynomial function of 4 variables that returns a 4D vector and is meant to be applied to all of the 750000 vectors.  Both codes below contain the same polynomial functions written in an explicit form (I have not included the full polynomials because they are long, and they are exactly the same).

For Mathematica, I am using a listable `Compile` with parallelization.

```
 Compile[{{f, _Real, 1}}, 
 {
   {0.011904761904761973` f[[2]]f[[1]]^3 + 
    0.002976190476190474` f[[1]]f[[2]]^3 - 0.020833333333333325` f[[3]] + 
    0.002976190476190474` f[[3]]^3 + 
    f[[2]]^2 (0.0029761904761904778` f[[3]] +...
   {0.002976190476190483` f[[1]]^3 + 0.011904761904761906` f[[2]]^3 - 
    0.0875` f[[3]] + 0.0029761904761904765` f[[3]]^3 + 
    f[[1]]^2 (0.005952380952380952` f[[2]] +...
 },CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  Parallelization -> True];

time = RepeatedTiming[testFunction[floatMatrix]];
Print["In Mathematica-C it takes an average of ", time[[1]], " secs."]
```

For Python I am using NumPy

```python
def testFunction(data):
    f1, f2, f3, f4 = data.T
    
    results = np.zeros((data.shape[0], 4))  # Initialize a results array

    results[:, 0] = (0.011904761904761973*f2*f1**3 + 0.002976190476190474*f1*f2**3 - 
                    0.020833333333333325*f3 + 0.002976190476190474*f3**3 + f2**2* 
                    (0.0029761904761904778*f3 +...
    results[:, 1] = (0.002976190476190483*f1**3 + 0.011904761904761906*f2**3 - 0.0875*f3
                   + 0.0029761904761904765*f3**3 + f1**2*(0.005952380952380952*f2 + 
                     0.002976190476190469*f3 + 0.0029761904761904726*f4) +...
    return results

duration=0

for i in range(10):
    start_time = time.time()
    testFunction(floatMatrix)
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = duration + end_time - start_time

duration=duration*0.1

print(f"With numpy it takes an average of': {duration} seconds")
```

As you can see it is a simple straightforward comparison. In my machine, Mathematica gets 0.1 secs and Python 0.4 secs (also in Google Colab). People often talk about NumPy as being incredibly fast this makes me think that either I am doing something wrong or those people don't know how to exploit Mathematica's parallelization and packed arrays.

Which one is it? Am I using the tools incorrectly?

EDIT: After I few suggestions by azerbajdzan I tried running the codes on a multi processor CPU. This time a 10 core. These are the results:

- Mathematica with `Parallelization -> True`: 0.0319974 seconds
- Mathematica with `Parallelization -> False`: **0.119938 seconds**
- Numpy: **0.206754 seconds**

So, the question still stands.

UPDATE: I have used @azerbajdzan suggestions and removed the transposing from inside of the function. I have created a continuation question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77167008/numpy-slower-than-mathematica). The python code without transposing is still slower than Mathematica's. They are both run in a single processor and produce the same output.

Comment: Am I right that Mathematica code runs on all your processors while the Python code only on one? If you want to compare performance you should test it on single processor in both cases.

Comment: What do you mean on single processor? I am testing them both on the same machine. Edit: I have a dual core CPU, do you think Mathematica is taking advantage of that but NumPy is not? That's why I tried to also run it in Colab and the timing was still worst than Mathematica in my computer. Which was unexpected.

Comment: Yes, same machine, but with `Parallelization -> True` you tell the compiler you want the code run on all processors. If you have 4 core processor then Mathematica code runs on all 4 of them. Your python code runs only on one core. But there are methods to parallelize also on Python.  Just search for "python parallelize". Remove the parameter `Parallelization -> True` and then compare the times. Or parallelize also python code.

Comment: I have removed the Parallelization part, the Mathematica code is still faster.

Comment: I have added an edit with the new running times.

Comment: So the times are quite the same on a single core, aren't they?

Comment: Same order of magnitud, with Mathematica still being about twice as fast each time. If I am not doing anything wrong, then what's all the fuzz about NumPy if Mathematica outperforms it single core and with just one Parallelization->True the code automatically runs in parallel. I am bit confused by all the people saying that Mathematica is slower than NumPy

Comment: Why you have to do transpose with `data.T` in python code? I do not see any transposing in Mathematica code, it surely slows down the code.

Comment: Ok, good point. However, I changed it for
```
def testFunction(data):
    f1 = data[:, 0]
    f2 = data[:, 1]
    f3 = data[:, 2]
    f4 = data[:, 3]
    
    results = np.zeros((data.shape[0], 4)) 
```

and it is still around 0.2 secs.

Comment: First, I don't understand why you expect an _uncompiled, interpretable (!)_ code in Python to be faster or comparable to a _compiled_ C code. Second, this question seems more about Python (or NumPy) than about Mathematica (you're not even using Mathematica, really, since you are just compiling it to C), and therefore more appropriate for some other StackExchange size.

Comment: @mmen: Are your two outputs of Mathematica and Python even the same? You are not doing any  changes in data in Mathematica code, but in python you transpose it whether with `data.T` or  with `f1 = data[:, 0] f2 = data[:, 1]...` you did not explain why.

Comment: @Domen: First, the vector operations in NumPy are run using C. Which is comparable to what Mathematica is doing and you can see that the times are comparable. Second, the question is about a benchmark comparison between Mathematica and NumPy. It pertains both. For example, azerbajdzan observation to make Parallelization->False in order to make the comparison fair, is Mathematica. Third, the main reason of why I expect NumPy to be faster is because everyone says it should be faster.

Comment: "Everyone says it should be faster" - you've got a reference for that?

Comment: you could give numba njit (parallel=True) a try, https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html

Comment: "Third, the main reason of why I expect NumPy to be faster is because everyone says it should be faster." LOL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare performance of two programming languages make sure:

- you test it on the same number of CPU cores - preferably on a single one
- both codes are doing the same - take the same input and produce the same output

Seems OP did not fulfill any of the two.

Comment: Both codes are running in the same number of cores and producing the same output.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77167008/numpy-slower-than-mathematica I have run the code doing the transposing outside of the function. It is still slow. I am using the same processor for both and I am stopping Mathematica from doing any parallelization.

Comment: You still have not explained why you are not doing any transpose in Mathematica but in Python you are.

Comment: Is just the way the functions are written in python for vectorization. The transposition is outside of the function that I am timing. Do you think that is still making the process slower?

Comment: Since you did not provide complete functional codes I can not even test anything.

Comment: Fair enough, I should present the question in a better form. Will work on that. I have learned a lot thank you for your suggestions.